# How to change a variable that is part of the value of another variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I currently have this function that will determine what account the database user should be:

```
calc_id_value(){
case $id_opt in
  "") id_value="$script_id@$SID"
      sql_in_db=$id_value
  ;;
  sys) id_value="sys/$sys_password@$SID as sysdba"
       sql_in_db=$id_value
  ;;
  system) id_value="system/$system_password@$SID"
          sql_in_db=$id_value
  ;;
  *) echo "Error in calc_id_value()"
  ;;
esac
}
```

Later, I will read each line of a list. Each line is a database. The below loop will go to each database and run the function called `sql_in` which just logs in and runs a file. The problem is that it will not go to the next database. It seems it is because it still interprets `$id_value` = `$script_id@$database1` when it should be = to `$script_id@databasen`.

```
while read sid
do
  SID=$sid
  export SID
#  calc_id_value
  sql_in_db=$id_value
  sql_in
done < "$list_value"
```

The problem is that it will not go to the next database. It seems it is because it continues to interpret `$id_value` = `$script_id@$database1` when it should be = to `$script_id@databasen`.

However, it works if I uncomment out `calc_id_value` within the loop. If I allow this, it feels like bad programming practice. I will then be forcing my current iteration of a loop to go back through a `case` statement that it. Is there a better way? If possible, I would like to be able to dynamically change the `$SID` part of the `id_value` variable after each line read.

Comment: How do you expect the value of `id_value` to change if you don't call `calc_id_value` in the loop? Also, what is `id_opt`: it's defined nowhere, yet it is used in the function.

Comment: @Nick, thank you for taking interest. `id_opt` is a parameter read in by `getops` function. I was trying not to over burden with code, I apologize if it was a misstep

Comment: It hurts my eyes to see names like `$id_value`. Since every variable holds a value, it's ok to simply call it `$id`

Comment: @kubanczyk, that's a fair point that I will take into my revisions, thanks

Comment: @Nick, I was expecting it to change because I was changing the value of `$SID` which is part of the definition of `id_value`. However, I'm clearly misunderstanding the concept in that.

Comment: But that's done *in* the function: if you don't call the function, there will be no change.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable but it's likely harmful. I would advice against that level of abstraction when scripting.

Consider whoever will read your script in future. In case of other source code, they will be programmers; in case of scripts they will probably be users or admins who will need some small fixes or small customizations. It's **uneconomical**  to use their time and mental capabilities just to save a little bit of processor time (or to get rid of subjective code smells). KISS is *the* paradigm for scripts.

Therefore please uncomment the code in the loop and don't "feel bad".

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't want to waste the time of other admins. I couldn't decide if making them go read another function over again is a waste of their time or valiantly simple, as opposed to just trying to reset the variable in one or 2 lines within the loop. Thank you for your input.